# how to reduce number of variables PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

My code checks and updates the number of apartments a building has with different bedrooms (1,2,3,4,studio) and calculates their avg min rent price and avg max rent price for particular type of room. How do I reduce the number of variables in this code so its easier to read and work with, if I can do it with arrays and foreach loop how can I use them in this code?

```
$room_one = $room_two = $room_three = $room_four = $room_studio = 0;
$rentmin_one = $rentmin_two = $rentmin_three = $rentmin_four = $rentmin_studio = 0;
$rentmax_one = $rentmax_two = $rentmax_three = $rentmax_four = $rentmax_studio = 0;
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    $field_bedrooms = "input field value";
    $field_rentmin = "input field value";
    $field_rentmax = "input field value";
      foreach ($field_bedrooms as $field_bedroom) {
        if (!is_null($field_bedroom) && !empty($field_bedroom)) {
          $bedrooms_nid = $field_bedroom['target_id'];
          $bedrooms_vocab = $this->load($bedrooms_nid);
          $bedroom_value = $bedrooms_vocab->getName();
          if ($bedroom_value == 1) {
            $room_one++;
            $rentmin_one = $rentmin_one + $field_rentmin;
            $rentmax_one = $rentmax_one + $field_rentmax;
          }
          elseif ($bedroom_value == 2) {
            $room_two++;
            $rentmin_two = $rentmin_two + $field_rentmin;
            $rentmax_two = $rentmax_two + $field_rentmax;
          }
          elseif ($bedroom_value == 3) {
            $room_three++;
            $rentmin_three = $rentmin_three + $field_rentmin;
            $rentmax_three = $rentmax_three + $field_rentmax;
          }
          elseif ($bedroom_value == 4 || $bedroom_value == '4+') {
            $room_four++;
            $rentmin_four = $rentmin_four + $field_rentmin;
            $rentmax_four = $rentmax_four + $field_rentmax;
          }
          elseif ($bedroom_value == 'Studio') {
            $room_studio++;
            $rentmin_studio = $rentmin_studio + $field_rentmin;
            $rentmax_studio = $rentmax_studio + $field_rentmax;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    $avg_minrent['one'] = !empty($rentmin_one) && !empty($room_one) ? $rentmin_one / $room_one : '';
    $avg_maxrent['one'] = !empty($rentmax_one) && !empty($room_one) ? $rentmax_one / $room_one : '';
    $avg_minrent['two'] = !empty($rentmin_two) && !empty($room_two) ? $rentmin_two / $room_two : '';
    $avg_minrent['three'] = !empty($rentmin_three) && !empty($room_three) ? $rentmin_three / $room_three : '';
    $avg_minrent['four'] = !empty($rentmin_four) && !empty($room_four) ? $rentmin_four / $room_four : '';
    $avg_minrent['studio'] = !empty($rentmin_studio) && !empty($room_studio) ? $rentmin_studio / $room_studio : '';
    $avg_maxrent['two'] = !empty($rentmax_two) && !empty($room_two) ? $rentmax_two / $room_two : '';
    $avg_maxrent['three'] = !empty($rentmax_three) && !empty($room_three) ? $rentmax_three / $room_three : '';
    $avg_maxrent['four'] = !empty($rentmax_four) && !empty($room_four) ? $rentmax_four / $room_four : '';
    $avg_maxrent['studio'] = !empty($rentmax_studio) && !empty($room_studio) ? $rentmax_studio / $room_studio : '';

return [f
 $avg_minrent,
 $avg_maxrent,
];
```

Comment: I suspect what you're looking for is an array of custom objects.  Each object would encapsulate the "room", "rentmin", and "rentmax" values.  And then you'd have an array (or another custom object with an array property of some sort) containing the 5 instances of that object.  Custom objects allow you to encapsulate related values into a single semantic instance of an object.

Comment: @David how to do that? can you reference some articles or other questions? thanks.

Comment: @David you need to read the PHP manual more.  https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If you have working code and you'd like to have it reviewed for potential improvement, please use [codereview.se] which is uniquely specialized in handling your question.  Please take their tour and read their How to Ask pages before posting your question there.